# Matlab Enumeration error

Tags: matlab, oop

I want to use an enumeration in Matlab. I follow a simlpy example as follow:

I created a classdef with the following enumeration and save it in a "*WeekDays.m*" file.

```
classdef WeekDays
   enumeration
      Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
   end
end
```

Then I tried to access its value from command window (still in the same directory where the "*WeekDays.m*" is located):

```
day = WeekDays.Monday;
```

However when I run the command, i received this error: "*Attempt to define enumeration without Enumeration class attribute in class 'WeekDays'* ".

How to use Enumeration correctly ? (By the way I'm using Matlab 2010)

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems to match [the documentation of the recent version](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/enumerations.html) are you sure that you saved the m file? And that it is on the path? -- If you worry that the syntax changed, use `doc enumerations` inside matlab to get the relevant version.

Comment: You will need to update your software. Custom enumerations were [added in MATLAB R2010b](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2010b/base/relnotes/f0-107996.html#f0-79433).

Comment: You are most likely using MATLAB R2010a.  As excaza pointed out, they were added as of R2010b.

Comment: Hi, yes you're right. I'm using matlab R2010a. I'll check again with matlab R2010b. Thanks